# merging two dictionaries but values adds up

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, c#-4.0

i have two dictionaries each of them has a string as key and an int as value i want to merge the two dictionaries but in case of duplicate keys the values get added up i had the idea of using loops to fill the 3rd dictionary but is there a simpler method that reduce time mainly

thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linq:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        IDictionary <string, int> dictA = new Dictionary <string, int>();
        dictA.Add("Apple", 2);
        dictA.Add("Banana", 1);

        IDictionary <string, int> dictB = new Dictionary <string, int>();
        dictB.Add("Apple", 1);
        dictB.Add("Cherry", 5);

        IDictionary <string, int> dictC = dictA.Concat(dictB)
            .GroupBy(i => i.Key)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Sum(j => j.Value));

        foreach(KeyValuePair <string, int> kvp in dictC) {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key: Apple, Value: 3
Key: Banana, Value: 1
Key: Cherry, Value: 5
```

Comment: that solved my problem thank you but will u kindly explain what these lines do exactly
.GroupBy(i => i.Key)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Sum(j => j.Value));